# Unmonitored (X.X.X.X:3306) Error in MEM tool

Tags: mysql, database-replication

We're seeing `"Unmonitored (X.X.X.11:3306)"` error in `MEM` tool due to below command executed on wrong Master server.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue without restarting the Master server.

ON Master X.X.X.10 :-

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='X.X.X.11', MASTER_USER='mysql',
MASTER_PASSWORD='paswd', MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.00XXXX',
MASTER_LOG_POS=61001479 ;
```

In the Replication Group, we're seeing this `Unmonitored (X.X.X.11:3306)` error & two red circles apart from the normal `Master (X.X.X.10:3306)` & `Slave (X.X.X.20:3306)` information.

How to remove the errored red circles & Unmonitored (X.X.X.11:3306) error.

Comment: Probably better to ask at http://dba.stackexchange.com or http://serverfault.com providing the output of `show slave status` command.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved when I execute the below command on the Master server and then restarted the MySQL Monitoring agent.

```
mysql> change master to Master_Host='';
ERROR 1210 (HY000): Incorrect arguments to MASTER_HOST



mysql> change master to Master_Host=' ';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.23 sec)
```

My MySQL version is : 5.5.8

Best,
Srinivas